# Create a trigger at the level of the server to validate inserts

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2014, I'm wondering if there is a way to create a trigger at the server level to validate inserts on same table but in different databases.
I don't want to put this trigger directly on the database because is something that I need to check on the development environment.

For example I have a SERVER-DEV with two databases, A and B each db have a table dbo.EmployeeType, I want to make sure people working on db A don't insert EmployeeType Ids that already exists on db B and vice-versa. This is just on development environment that's why I'm looking for something extra db like the server.

I tried with CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name ON ALL SERVER but looks like there is nothing for what I want.

Comment: No there is not a server level trigger that will be applied to any database that has a table with the same name. If you want a trigger you have to put it on the table.

Comment: ok thank you for the quick answer